# Sql sorting in php page

Tags: php, sql, json, sorting

Hello am looking for some help in sorting data in specific sorting or a guide to follow :

i have  a table ,containe two index latitude and longitude,  and in  the other hand inside the web page i have a latitude  and longitude:

i did the query to get all lat and long from the table and here i stopped  i have a function to make the calculation

```
function distance() {

$lat1= 36.2048;
$lang1= 138.2529;
$query = "select * from locations";
$var = $con->query($query);
while($row_info = $var->fetch()){

  $lat2= $row_info['lat'];
  $lang= $row_info['long'];
    if(($lat1 == $lat2) && ($lon1 == $lon2)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
        $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
        $dist = acos($dist);
        $dist = rad2deg($dist);
        $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        $unit = strtoupper($unit);

        if ($unit == "K") {
            return ($miles * 1.609344);
        } else if ($unit == "N") {
            return ($miles * 0.8684);
        } else {
            return $miles;
        }
    }
}}
```

i need to make a calculation that compares lat and long that i got from the query with the existing one in the  web page and order them Desc to get them again in the new query?

Comment: Normally the best place to sort the data is as part of the query using `ORDER BY`. Can you show us the query?

Comment: You could also do all this calculation as part of the query

Comment: @RiggsFolly   how is that give lead or something please.

Comment: Show us your query and we can make sensible accurate suggestions

Comment: Oki I'll try to make further explination   on the question

Comment: What do you want to sort the results on? Descending on what column?

Comment: ok lets say we have a location for japan the location has a latitude and longitude  , and i  have a table conatin countries with their locations [latitude and longitude] 
and i want to show countries  distance  from japan in ascending or descending 
according   to the result after the calculation of the distance done .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: here's an example how to do the distance calculation (in miles) directly with the query:

```
$lat1= 36.2048;
$lang1= 138.2529;
$query = "select * from locations";

$query = 'SELECT *, CASE
    WHEN '. $lat1 .' = `lat` && '. $lang1 .' = `long` THEN
        0
    ELSE
        DEGREES(ACOS(
            SIN(RADIANS(`lat`)) * SIN(RADIANS('. $lat1 .')) +
            COS(RADIANS(`lat`)) * COS(RADIANS('. $lat1 .')) * COS(RADIANS(`long`-'. $lang1 .'))
            ))
        * 69.09
    END as distance
FROM `locations`
ORDER BY distance desc';
```

Old Answer:

You could use `usort` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

here's an example:

```
//global lat / lan from page
$lat = 46.945252; 
$lon = 7.424627;

//query results
$data = [
    ['name'=>'coords1','lat'=>47.348121, 'lon'=>7.903737],
    ['name'=>'coords2','lat'=>47.378104, 'lon'=>8.536811]
];

usort($data,function($a,$b) {
    global $lat, $lon;
    $distA = distance($a['lat'],$a['lon'],$lat,$lon,'K');
    $distB = distance($b['lat'],$b['lon'],$lat,$lon,'K');
    if ($distA > $distB) {
        return -1;
    } else if ($distA < $distB) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});

//now $data is sorted according to distance (desc)
```

Comment: thank you for replying this fast  
so what i understand for this is  you wanted me to insert the query result inside array ,and make the calculation for each , but after that in need to summarize the result with [id ,calculation result] so i can get further info from the same raw with a new query.

Comment: right, if you have to get further information with a new query, it would be better to shift the calculation part also to the query - do you maybe have an example of some data and some information on the further info you have to get?

Comment: Done editing the question , thank you for your concern.

Comment: I added an exmaple how to do the calculation within the query - now the question is what do you want to do with the result - if it is another query, this could possibly also be done within this one